# Adding multiple column of a row in sql DB

Tags: android, sql

I have a sql data table. I have multiple column for my android aplication like

```
studentID,studentName,Day1,Day2,Day3,.......DayN.
```

Now I want to keep sum value in an integer variable like an array. Sum will be of Day as example 1+0+1+....+1. if the column value of a row for each studentID have 1 then will count 1, else will count 0 and make them sum. How can I do it? If You can help me with code. For helping me, advance thanks.

Comment: In case of 0 what output you want?

Comment: I want to add Day1, Day2,...DayN values. But if it be 0 or anything else, it will count 0 instead of 1.

Comment: See answer below.If works please upvote.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A case when statement creates a column based on conditions. For example if Day1, Day2 are integers which can either be 1 or zero, then according to you question I would write.

```
select studentID,studentName, sum(case when Day1+Day2+Day3 <3 then 0 else 1 end) as derived_col
from table
group by studentID,studentName
```

Because u wanted to aggregate it post the condition

Now if you have too many date columns and its cumbersome to write it out then u'll have to try out something else

Comment: Sir, I have multiple column till DayN. Not only till Day3. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: Use `pragma table_info(yourTableName)` to get the table details.

Answer (score 0):

Write the query like this :

Here x=Number of day columns.

```
select studentID,studentName,case when sum(Day1+Day2+...+DayN) <x then 0 else 1 end as dayCount
from table
```

In `dayCount` column you will get your desired output.

And if you want just the sum then use like :

```
select studentID,studentName,sum(Day1+Day2+...+DayN)  as dayCount
from table group by studentID,studentName
```

Comment: Sir, when I don't know the number of days because of multiple column in dynamically adding everyday, how I will give the column name in sum function?? Any loop needed? If it's needed , so how?

Comment: Use `pragma table_info(yourTableName)` to get the table details.